# Assistance with Python's ast.literal_eval('a_string')

Tags: python, eval, string-literals

I've been trying to get Python3s **ast.literal_eval**() function to work (in an interactive Python session) but -- and I read it's doc description -- I cannot.

My goal is to replace this:

```
>>> import logging
>>> eval('logging.DEBUG')
10
```

with the safer alternative, this:

```
>>> import logging, ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('logging.DEBUG')
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Attribute object at 0x7f1ccc55eeb8>
```

but the latter doesn't work (at least not how I am using it). Note that I also tried *triple-quoted* and *raw-string* variations, too.

I believe I'm simply missing a nuance here (e.g. it's possible that it may not like evaluating constants in a module). From the Python-3 documentation on **ast.literal_eval**():

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a **string** containing a Python
>   literal or container display. The string or node provided may only
>   consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes,
>   numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python
>   values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values
>   oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex
>   expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.

Any help appreciated. =:) Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the *literal* part of `literal_eval`. `literal_eval("'logging.DEBUG'")` -> `'logging.DEBUG'`. You can only evaluate literals, i.e. strings, tuples, dicts, numbers, etc. and get the same data type out of it that you passed in as its string reprensentation. That's kinda the point.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that scenario, too (precisely because of the literal wording). :). I'm guess I'm trying (and it may not be possible here) to get the syntax for using something safer than eval(). There used to be a safe_eval somewhere. But I'm trying this first.

Comment: A little more context: I'm using configparser.SafeConfigParser() to derive a k/v pair: log_level = "logging.DEBUG". That, of course, results in an identifier that points to a string (which isn't a literal); but which, nevertheless, needs to be evaluated into a log-level integer value. eval() works but I prefer not to use it. As I mentioned in the post, it may not be possible here, but I wanted to ask the community. :)

Comment: Couldn't you use a dictionary that maps strings to values? `{'logging': {'DEBUG': 10}, ...}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the context you give in comment, I advice you not to do that:

- you cannot use `ast.literal_eval` because `logging.Debug` is not a litteral: you ask a value from a module, and that could have arbitrary side effects
- you should not use eval for a value that is read from an external file.

My advice would be to use a map:

```
log_levels = { 'DEBUG': logging.DEBUG, ... }
```

When you later read `log_level` (say DEBUG) from your config file, you just do:

```
real_level = log_levels[log_level]
```

That way you can easily accept case errors with `real_level = log_levels[log_level.upper()]`, and if there is an unexpected value in the config file, you just get a `KeyError` exception, with no risk of unwanted evaluation.

Comment: Hello there. As @timgeb originally alluded above (in his comment), I had a debug level dict implementation already (defined in a module. It's my general approach, in fact). But wanted to ask about this. I guess I'll revert to a dict. I'll circle back around to check off a solution but, meanwhile, I upvoted your answer and timgeb's comments, too (both of them). Thank guys.